# There is an estimation of a $ \sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_p} \left(\frac{a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...a_0}{p} \right) \le (n-1)\sqrt{p}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, estimation

Where can I find a proof of the following inequality? ( $n$ is odd)

$$
\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_p} \left(\frac{a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...a_0}{p} \right) \le (n-1)\sqrt{\vphantom{d}p}
$$

I read that Helmut Hasse (for $n = 3$) and Andre Weil (for any $n$) proved that inequality, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Write your latex in between $ .

Comment: What order do you consider on $\mathbf F_p$?

Comment: $x = 1, 2 , ... , p-1$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/hasse-weil-bound/